# How to remove part of string with Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to strip the following;

**INPUT:**

```
[color=00ff08]100[/color](3.0/3.0)
```

The `=00ff08` will change given the `color`, so that has to be variable.

**OUTPUT:**

```
100(3.0/3.0)
```

Basically I want to remove `[color=*****]` and `[/color]` from the `string`.

Thanks, I'm so horrible at `regex`.  Maybe I should get a book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: [This](https://regexr.com) is a good place for training on `regex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub`

**Demo:**

```
import re

s = """INPUT [color=00ff08]100[/color](3.0/3.0)"""

text = re.sub("\[color=.*?\]", "", s)
text = re.sub("\[/color\]", "", text)  

print(text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very clear and in Python.  You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'(.*)'
       r'\[color=[^\]]*\]'
       r'([^\[]*)'
       r'\[/color\]'
       r'(.*)', r'\1\2\3', my_string)
```

This captures the relevant parts into groups, ignores the remaining parts and stitches the result together again.

Doing it like this doesn't cloak problems in the input.  If you like a more robust solution (which also works decently for slightly wrong input), have a look at @Rakesh's answer.  His would also work for inputs like `INPUT 100[/color][/color](3.0/3.0)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that works for all tags:

```
a = "[color=00ff08]100[/color](3.0/3.0)"
re.sub("\\[[^]]*]", "", a)
```

Output:

```
'100(3.0/3.0)'
```